# Random generating a array of enum with no repeat elements (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, enums

I am trying to generate a array of enum with no same elements, but what I have done still gives me repeat elements

```
const int MAXNO = 6;
enum Fruit {Durian, Papaya, Apple, Orange, Mango, Jackfruit, Strawberry};

int main ()
{
    srand (time (NULL));

    int size = rand () % 6 + 1;

    Fruit f [size];
    cout << "Size: " << size << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        f[i] = static_cast <Fruit>(rand() % MAXNO);

        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            do 
            {
                f[i] = static_cast <Fruit>(rand() % MAXNO);

            }while(f[i] == f[j]);
        }       
        cout << f[i] << endl;

    }
}
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: `Fruit f [size];` where `size` is not a compile time constant, is invalid as C++ code, though it can be accepted by some compilers as a language extension (then probably modeled on C99 variadic arrays). Use a `std::vector` instead.

Comment: A simple way to fill an array with 0, 1, 2, 3, and so forth, is to use `std::iota`. Then shuffle that array using `std::shuffle`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, even i changed to a const number, it still have repeat elements

Comment: Why do you expect your inner for loop to prevent duplicates?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, I am not allow to use things that I have not learnt in class to code. so vector and shuffle and iota, I cannot use. Thanks anyway

Comment: btw, `MAXNO` looks like a macro. A better name would be `max_no`.

Comment: @ChristianHackl, i use the inner for loop to compare the current element to the elements in the array.

Comment: Your inner loop can pick some other already existing fruit from some other position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner loop is meant to check the other array elements for duplicates, but you terminate the check prematurely as soon as *one* element is not a duplicate. In other words, you don't search for duplicates, **you search for non-duplicates**.

Let's say `i` is 2, `f[0]` is `Apple` and `f[1]` is `Orange`.

The inner loop starts, `j` is 0.

`f[i] = static_cast <Fruit>(rand() % MAXNO);` creates an `Orange`. It should be detected as a duplicate, but it is not.

How comes?

It's because in the `do...while` condition, you compare `f[2]` with `f[0]`. They are not equal, so the loop terminates.

A quick fix to this, based on your original approach, is to compare all elements for equality, ideally in a separate function:

```
bool exists(Fruit* begin, Fruit* end, Fruit fruit)
{
    for (Fruit* iter = begin; iter != end; ++iter)
    {
        if (*iter == fruit)
        {
            return true;
        } 
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then change your loops to something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    bool duplicate = false;
    do
    {
        f[i] = static_cast <Fruit>(rand() % MAXNO);
        duplicate = exists(f, f + i, f[i]);
    } while (duplicate);
}
```

But this solution still has its share of problems, the most serious (in my opinion) being that the loop termination condition depends on random luck. In theory, the program might loop for a very long time or even forever.

A much better design would be to use all the standard C++ features which your teacher apparently doesn't allow you to use (safe containers and predefined algorithms), and reconsider your entire program logic. Other answers and comments have already covered that sufficiently.

Comment: Some words about inefficiency and loop termination could improve this answer greatly, IMHO. Also, simply presenting the standard solution.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Maybe. I thought the answer might be more accessible if it was based on the OP's original approach and actually explained why precisely it didn't work as intended. As for the standard solution, others have already covered it; unfortunately, the OP's teacher doesn't seem to "allow" it anyway (sigh).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: That being said, that thing about loop termination is an important point, so I'll add it. Thanks! :)

Comment: @ChristianHackl, I tried using pointers with similar codes to check duplicates, but it still give me duliplicates, will you help me to see which part of my codes went wrong? Thanks a lot!
https://pastebin.com/U0yve2rQ

Comment: @engkhsky: I never look at code posted on remote sites, but you may of course ask a new question on Stack Overflow if you can also provide an MCVE.

Comment: @ChristianHackl, ok thanks I think i will ask a new question, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Get array whit enum length and initial with 0,And for every random enum produce check the index in that array is 0 , if true make the index of enum on that array 1.

Get array whit length of enum size
And initial with 0

```
int produced_value[MAXNO] = {0}; //be new array
-------------------------
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
-------------------------
```

And this array show which enum produced before.
Every time you generate random enum and want to be not produced before check with that array. if index in that array is  zero that not produced before and not repeatedly element use it and update your array.

For Example

```
int a;
while(produced_value[(a = rand() % MAXNO)]); //this loop find a that value in produced_value is 0
/* if a == 2 then should update array
    -------------------------
    | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
    ---------~~~-------------
*/
produced_value[a] = 1; // mark 'a' as produced 

//Then use Unique int in the enum range
f[i] = static_cast <Fruit>(a);
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the part  "every enum produce randomly check the index in that array is 0". Can you explain again?

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty reasonable that you get duplicates if you pick an element at random from a collection and then you make that element ready for being picked up again.

I would suggest another approach. Why don't you first randomly sort the array of enums and then pick the first `size` element? In this way you don't get duplicates and always have the first `size` element in random order. 
Also note that you have `7` enums, which means that `MAXNO` should be `7` otherwise expressions like `int size = rand () % MAXNO;` would never return `6` which is a valid enum in your list `Strawberry`.

Something, as follows, should work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;
const int MAXNO = MAXNO*2;
enum Fruit {Durian, Papaya, Apple, Orange, Mango, Jackfruit, Strawberry};
int main ()
{
    srand (time (NULL));

    Fruit ff [Strawberry+1] = {Durian, Papaya, Apple, Orange, Mango, Jackfruit, Strawberry};
    const int NIT = 7;
    for(int i=0 ; i < NIT ; i++ ){
        const int ii = (rand() % MAXNO);
        const int jj = (rand() % MAXNO);
        swap(ff[ii],ff[jj]);
    }

    //simply output the firse `size` element
    //from the randomly ordered array.
    const int size = rand () % MAXNO;
    for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
        cout<<ff[i]<<endl;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't create a variable length array, just use vector:

> Fruit f [size];

The enum type is not relevant here, so to solve your problem you can just create a vector with all the possible int values and then shuffle the vector ([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0ab8efa8831d0846)):

```
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>


const int MAXNO = 6;

int main ()
{
     std::vector<int> v;
     v.reserve(MAXNO);

     for (int i = 0; i < MAXNO; ++i)
     {
        v.push_back(i);   
     }

    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 g(rd());

    std::shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), g);

    for (auto& e: v)
    {
        std::cout << e << " ";
    }
}
```

> 3 4 0 1 2 5

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code:
If you had any problem on this let me know

```
enum Fruit {Durian, Papaya, Apple, Orange, Mango, Jackfruit, Strawberry};
```

private std::vector ::RanomFruit()
{
    auto baseList = new List {Fruit::Durian, Fruit::Papaya, Fruit::Apple, Fruit::Orange, Fruit::Mango, Fruit::Jackfruit, Fruit::Strawberry};

```
auto fruitArray = std::vector<Fruit>(7);
Random *random = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
{
    int randNumber = random->Next(6 - i);
    fruitArray[i] = baseList[randNumber];
    baseList->RemoveAt(randNumber);

}

return fruitArray;
```

}

Comment: This is not even C++.